# Livecharts remove axis

Tags: c#, livecharts

How do I remove axis from Livecharts?

```
cartesianChart1.Series.Remove(object value)
```

But what is the object value?

This is how I'm adding the series:

```
cartesianChart1.Series.Add(new LineSeries
{
    Values = ValuesLinearity,
    StrokeThickness = 2,
    PointGeometrySize = 0,
    DataLabels = false,
    Title = "Linearity Error % new",
    ScalesYAt = 1,
    Stroke = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 0)),
    Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Transparent,
    LineSmoothness = 1,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

SeriesCollection.Remove(SeriesCollection[0]);

I ran into the same issue and this solution worked for me:

In the constructor of my MainWindow I created a seriescollection like so:

```
        // Setup the chart
        SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection
        {
            new LineSeries
            {
                Title = "Series 1",
                Values = new ChartValues<double> { 4, 6, 5, 2  }
            },
            new LineSeries
            {
                Title = "Series 2",
                Values = new ChartValues<double> { 6, 7, 3, 4  }
            }
        };
```

Then, I used a Click event on a button to run this line:

SeriesCollection.Remove(SeriesCollection[0]);

To answer your question, the "object value" is the name of the variable (in this case, type ), including the array index of which series in the series collection you want to remove.

Answer (score -1):

```
cartesianChart1.Series.Clear();
```